# db_insert() for CCK

Tags: 7, database

I've created a custom module in D7, wich gothers info from user via form.api.
Next, I've created a Custom Content Type 'questions' where I setup fields according to my form.

How do I save data to the CCK?

Note: 
I've tryed db_insert(), but it refers only to 'node' which nsert one or more records to the node table.

```
    $nid = db_insert('node') // Table name no longer needs {}
->fields(array(
  'title' => 'Example',
  'uid' => 1,
  'created' => REQUEST_TIME,
))
->execute();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never insert into the node (or any other entity table) directly, there's a fully-fledged API for handling such things. At the moment you're bypassing a lot of the core goodness that the node module offers, and you're likely to run into problems (you're not updating the revision table for example).

[`node_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_save/7) is the best tool for the job here:

```
$node = new stdClass;
$node->type = 'the_type';
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;

node_object_prepare($node);

// Add a field
$node->field_some_field[$node->language][0]['value'] = 'Some value';

// Save the node
node_save($node);

// The node is saved by this point so the nid is available.
$nid = $node->nid;
```

Comment: Thanks, for prompt responce. I am feeling so stupid because of searching at wrong direction:)

Comment: @Jim, the documentation for this is really scattered.  Once you start getting familiar with the terminology, you can target searches better.